# Datepicker Jquery Ajax Based Limiting of Dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datepicker

I have been scratching my head for a while then i found some code on here posted a long while back that did the trick, however its only updating the one month and the object even though is called by ajax seems not to be refreshed properly.

My JS is poor and i can only make heads and tales with the programing knowledge i have, the JSON output is working great and dose pump out the values i need.

I have 1 select box with a market dropdown selectbox
2 Datepickers (From and To).

The MarketID is being pulled correctly but i still cant tell what the issue is, only have data for 2011-Dec to 2012 Feb in terms of dates and only Dec 2011 is shown. Even when i try the json feed their is data.

If you guys could give me a hand with this it would be great!

```
<script>
var allowedDates = new Object();

function queryAllowedDates (year, month, id, market) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/pstars/api/api_calendardates.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) { 
      allowedDates[id] = response.allowedDates;
    },
    data: {year:year,month:month,market:market},
    async: false
  });
}

$("#date_from").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
  changeMonth: true, 
  changeYear: true ,
  beforeShow: function (input) {
    var currentDate = $(input).datepicker('getDate');
    var id = $(input).attr('id');
    var marketid = $('#d_market').val(); 
    queryAllowedDates(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth()+1,id,marketid);
  },
  onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
    var marketid = $('#d_market').val();
    queryAllowedDates(year, month, inst.input.attr('id'),marketid);
  },
  beforeShowDay: function (day) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    var date_str = [
      day.getFullYear(),
      day.getMonth() + 1,
      day.getDate()
    ].join('-');

    if (allowedDates[id] != undefined && allowedDates[id][date_str]) {
      return [true, 'good_date', 'This date is selectable'];
    } else {
      return [false, 'bad_date', 'This date is NOT selectable'];
    } 
  }
});

$("#date_to").datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
      changeMonth: true, 
      changeYear: true ,
      beforeShow: function (input) {
        var currentDate = $(input).datepicker('getDate');
        var id = $(input).attr('id');
        var marketid = $('#d_market').val(); 
        queryAllowedDates(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth()+1,id,marketid);
      },
      onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
        var marketid = $('#d_market').val();
        queryAllowedDates(year, month, inst.input.attr('id'),marketid);
      },
      beforeShowDay: function (day) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        var date_str = [
          day.getFullYear(),
          day.getMonth() + 1,
          day.getDate()
        ].join('-');

        if (allowedDates[id] != undefined && allowedDates[id][date_str]) {
          return [true, 'good_date', 'This date is selectable'];
        } else {
          return [false, 'bad_date', 'This date is NOT selectable'];
        } 
      }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Example json ajax input:


`{"allowedDates":{"2012-02-01":1,"2012-02-02":1,"2012-02-06":1,"2012-02-09":1}}`